# How to declare variables in T-SQL from select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, variable-assignment, declare

```
declare @Week nvarchar(16) = quotename(concat('Week',@CID,@SID));
declare @Week2 nvarchar(256) = concat('SELECT TOP 1 [Year],[Week] FROM',@Week,'GROUP BY [Year],[Week] ORDER BY [Year] DESC,[Week] DESC');

exec sp_executesql @Week2
```

how can I declare @Year and @Week respectively from the result of exec sp_executesql @Week2? (declare as in assign the result values into @year and @week)

Thanks

```
declare @latestyear NVARCHAR(50), @latestweek NVARCHAR(50)
declare @Week2 nvarchar(256) = 'SELECT TOP 1 @latestyear=[Year],@latestweekweek=[Week] FROM [Week45] GROUP BY [Year],[Week] ORDER BY [Year] DESC,[Week] DESC';
exec sp_executesql @Week2
PRINT @latestyear
PRINT @latestweek
```

The above doesn't seem to work for me

Also trying to do this in 1 select statement if possible

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation at all? The whole point of using parameters is to avoid dynamic SQL

Comment: If you try to pass the table name as a parameter - you're doing it wrong, whatever it is you try to do. Tables are the same as types in a strongly typed language, not parameters. If you need to manage and move large amounts of data by partitioning, use [actual table partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of having multiple tables with date suffixes

Comment: If you already have lots of tables with suffixes (bad idea) use a `VIEW` to combine them instead of trying to pick the table in the query. If the `Year` and `Week` columns have constraints on what values are allowed, the database engine will pick the correct table automatically because it *knows* the other tables can't possibly have any matching data.